# How to setup Chrome Browser on MacOS (or Windows) so that only SSL connections are allowed?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

Due to security concerns we would like to Chrome Browser on MacOS (or Windows) allows only SSL (https) connections. I.e., if host does not support https then it will not allowed. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a [proxy auto-config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file that provides an invalid proxy for all non-https URLs. Unfortunately, Chrome uses the system-wide proxy settings, so you'd need to change this for everything.
[image]